# Behavior of List Views in Lightning - Auto Refresh feature on updation of records

Tags: lightning, list-view, streaming-api

We are looking for any approaches to make the list views refresh automatically to show new records that got created on backed and fall under the list view category. Seems to be out of box salesforce doesn't support this feature.

But on list views we are seeing a note saying ***'Updated a minute ago'***

[image]

Trying to understand how exactly this works or what this is meant by, haven't found any relevant document explaining this on salesforce docs.

Reference to any related documentation would be helpful.